# alternate views landscape and portrait for one xib file?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ibaction

I have three views in my .xib file. The first one is the normal view of my Viewcontroller with no subviews.

Then i create the same views for portrait and landscape . All three have to be root-level views (have a look at the screenshot)

[image]

my main question is that i have one IBAction in .m file and i put the  UIButton on both the view (portrait and landscape) used same action because my both view have same look and done same job .

After click on RUN ,, simulator show portrait view and i click on button its work ,,then rotate simulator , it shows landscape view and i click on button it call same IBAction and work properly.

But the problem is that when i rotate the simulator three  time then portrait view's buttopn work properly  but  landscape view's button not work .... whats the main problem .....

```
     #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize landscapeView, portraitView ;

    @synthesize scrollView,pageControl,toolBar;

   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {
                 // Custom initialization
         }
    return self;
    }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]    statusBarOrientation];
[self setUpViewForOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}


   -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
[self setUpViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    }

   -(void)setUpViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
   {
[currentView removeFromSuperview];

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{
    [self.view addSubview:landscapeView];

    currentView = landscapeView;
}
else
{

    [self.view addSubview:portraitView];
     currentView = portraitView;


}

   }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  -(IBAction)print:(id)sender
 {
NSLog(@"ok click ...");
 }


         @end
```

plz solved it ????

Comment: please help me any one .......

Comment: did you write out additional code to switch from portrait to landscape? if so, most likely some error there. If you did *not* write any additional code, just delete your "View Landscape" View completely to see any difference.

Comment: Are you targetting ios7 device? I think willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: is deprecated. maybe try using viewWillLayoutSubviews: instead for testing n doing your rotation.